# Setting width:auto leads to width:100%

Tags: html, css

I am a little bit tired right now (out of coffee), so I am unable to figure this out.

When I set `p.style.width = auto` (the blue one), why is its `width` at **100%**? None of the elements have their width set to 100%, so I doubt it's inherited property.

How can I set the `<p>`'s width to match its content width plus padding?

Sample page [link](http://elijen.ic.cz/hs)

Comment: And of course how can I fix it? How can I set <p>'s width to match its content width+padding ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `width:auto` defaults to **100%** (that is, minus borders and paddings, see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width)), if you are not in a **floating / positioned** environment. Actually, without

```
float:left
```

or

```
position: absolute
```

you're quite out of luck setting the width of an element to a minimum in CSS only. See, e.g., [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/width) for how you could achieve it in Firefox (only).

**Edit:** You could also use

```
display: table;
width: auto;
```

but, for one, this is also not supported in all browsers and then the table design may bring you in all kinds of other trouble.

**Edit 2:** You might, as suggested by DisgruntledGoat, also try `display:inline-block`. [This page](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) gives a cross-browser implementation targeting IE6+, FF2+, Safari 3+ and Opera.

Comment: That's strange behaviour. I would expect width:auto means width = (sum of children widths + padding).

I think I'll use the position: absolute here, but how could I achieve the same with relative positioned element without float? (cross-browser) There is no clear solution available?

Comment: Unfortunately, this field is as tricky as, e.g., vertically centered content. Try one of the solutions (of the other answers as well), and in 99% of all cases you find one that is ok for your design. In all other cases, JavaScript is a necessary friend.

Answer (score 5):

It's all explained in the spec

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth

O.O

Essentially, auto means taking all the other specified paddings, borders and margins into account, fill the remaining space (assuming only the width is set to auto).  So effectively 100% minus borders, padding and margins.

To fix, just set it to match the other elements, or stick them all in a containing element with a set width.

Answer (score 4):

The others are right, `width: auto` sets the width to fill all available space.

One solution would be to use `display: inline-block`, which should do what you want. For compatibility with IE6 it's best to apply that to an inline element like `<span>`. And add `display: -moz-inline-box` for Firefox 2 and earlier.

Comment: I have nothing against floats but I think this is the more elegant solution.