# Floating a div without specifying a width

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I can float an image on the left and have the text wrap around it no problem just by specifying `float: left` on the image. Like this:

```
<div id='foo'>

  <img src='bar' alt='baz' style='float: left;' />
  Lorem ipsum...

</div>
```

However if the image is wrapped in a div like the following i cannot achieve the same effect without declaring a fixed width on both the `div#image_container` and the `div#text_container`

```
<div id='image_container'>
  <img src='blah' alt='blah' />
</div>

<div id='text_container'>
  Lorem ipsum... long text
</div>
```

Is there a way to keep the flexibility of the first solution and avoid declaring a width and have the `div#image_container` float next to the `div#text_container`?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042645/setting-widthauto-leads-to-width100

Comment: @Boldewyn i applied display: inline-block to the wrapper div of my #text_container and #image_container but it works only if the width of the text is shorter than the remaining width. Should i really go calculate the width with js?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper div, that should automatically set the div to the width of the image.

---

OK maybe I misunderstood your question. Do you just want the text to flow around the image? If so, all you should need is this CSS:

```
#text_container { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Like Colt .45...

Works every time.

Comment: I still need to set the width on the text_container

Answer (score 0):

```
#text_container,
#image_container {
  display: inline;
}
```

should do it. Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        #top {
            float: left;
            display: inline;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }

        #bottom {
            float: right;
            display: inline;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="top">
        I'm the top div
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        I'm the bottom div
    </div>
</html>
```

But if the content of your div's is bigger than the width you've left for them (which it probably is) then you will struggle. You should really give it a width but the above might work for you depending on how you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks, this does work if the text is shorter than the width (which is not in my case) :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the text container use a paragraph tag (`<p></p>`). It will wrap around the content plus it is more accessible and semantic.

Comment: I like to wrap code in native html tags. I limit divs to template level coding hence that is why I would use a paragraph tag.